# How to put label on top of Custom Tkinter Scrollable Frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

I want to make a scroll for some of the frames for my project with custom tkinter.

I tried making a scrolledFrame instead of a standard Frame.
However, when I define the scrolled frame as follows:

```
homePage = ctk.CTkScolledFrame(window, width=300, height=400) #the dimensions of my window
```

And I put a label on it:

```
label = ctk.CTkLabel(homePage, text='Hello').place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

It gives me an undesired output of the label being cut off at the top of the screen. For some reason, the scrolledFrame is not allowing the label to be put on it.

The output is attached as an image.

There is not much documentation provided on ctk, except for this link here on scrollable frames:
https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/tutorial/scrollable-frames

I even tried making a class like in the documentation examples, but I'm inexperienced with those and its giving errors.

[image]

Comment: There is no `CTkScrolledFrame`, do you mean `CTkScrollableFrame` instead?  Note that using `place()` on the label will not adjust the size of its parent, so the height of the frame will be 1. What is the point of using `.place()` if you want a scrollable frame?

Comment: Oh, yes, I mean CTkScrollableFrame. As for putting .place() on the label, I did that so I could place the label on the frame itself. Do you know a way that I can place the label on the frame?

Comment: Use `pack()` or `grid()` instead.